# Data I'm trying to scrape cut short

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use Python to scrape the play-by-play table from this [basketball-reference example](http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201505020LAC.html) into a CSV file.

When I run this code, the table is cut short and many cells are missing. I'm a programming n00b and any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import csv

bref = "http://www.basketball-reference.com"
print "Enter game code:"
game = raw_input("> ")

def make_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "lxml")

def get_pbp(pbp):
    soup = make_soup(bref + "/boxscores/pbp/" + game + ".html")
    table = soup.find("table", "no_highlight stats_table")
    rows = [row.find_all("td") for row in table.find_all("tr")]

    data = []
    for row in rows:
        values = []
        for value in row:
            if value.string is None:
                values.append(u"")
            else:
                values.append(value.string.replace(u"\xa0", u""))
        data.append(values)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "Writing data for game " + game

    with open(game + '.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(get_pbp(game))

    print game + " has been successfully scraped."
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *skip empty cells*:

```
table = soup.find("table", class_="no_highlight stats_table")
rows = [[cell.text.replace(u"\xa0", u"").strip() for cell in row.find_all("td") if cell.text.strip()]
        for row in table.find_all("tr")[2:]]

with open(game + '.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to replace empty cells with blank strings ("")? Also, the whole table is still being cut off at line 257 for some reason.

Comment: @Chris not sure, it works for me. Tested using http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201504140IND.html.